# Use of parentheses in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am learning Swift and just had a quick question about use of parentheses. The code below runs just fine w/o using parentheses, but it certainly looks a lot cleaner using them in this instance.

So my question is: In SwiftUI, is it basic practice to use parentheses for the sake of cleanliness? Might be a silly question - but am new and eager to learn.

```
let currentHR = 147

let isInTarget = (currentHR >= targetLowerBound) && (currentHR <= targetUpperBound)
let isBelowTarget = (currentHR < targetLowerBound)
let isAboveTarget = (currentHR > targetUpperBound)

if (isInTarget == true) {
    print("You're right on track!")
} else if (isBelowTarget == true) {
    print("You're doing great, but to try to push it a bit!")
} else {
    print("You're on fire! Slow it down just a bit")
}
```

Comment: On this site is is expected that you post code from working project, with sufficient context to be reviewed. General “best practices” questions are off-topic. Compare https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I am not sure if this falls outside the [guidelines for “best practices” questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). This isn't necessarily “purely generic, hypothetical code.” I guess it _could_ be, but it could just as easily be from a real project...

Comment: In that case the question author should present the purpose of that code (in the question title and body). In its present form (*“So my question is: In SwiftUI, is it basic practice to use parentheses for the sake of cleanliness?”*)  it *is* a best practices question, as I see it. – It is unfortunate that even after two days the author did not reply to those concerns.

Comment: Sorry for the very late response - I missed these. I really appreciate everyones input and corrections, and I apologize for not correcting the title.

Answer (score 1):

A few observations:

1. When using Booleans, we would generally not use the `== true` test, much less the parentheses. E.g. from [The Swift Programming Language: The Basics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#)

   > Boolean values are particularly useful when you work with conditional statements such as the `if` statement:
   >
   > ```swift
   > if turnipsAreDelicious {
   >     print("Mmm, tasty turnips!")
   > } else {
   >     print("Eww, turnips are horrible.")
   > }
   > ```

   So, in your example, you might do:

   ```swift
   if isInTarget {
       print("You're right on track!")
   } else if isBelowTarget {
       print("You're doing great, but to try to push it a bit!")
   } else {
       print("You're on fire! Slow it down just a bit")
   }
   ```

   In this case, the use of the `== true` would be considered unnecessary syntactic noise.
2. Regarding the use of redundant parentheses in Swift (e.g. `if (isInTarget) { ... }`), they are generally omitted. To most of our eyes, including redundant parentheses does not improve readability. In fact, if one includes redundant parentheses, the code tends to feel like Swift code written by an Objective-C programmer (because these these parentheses are required by Objective-C, but not Swift).

   FWIW, linters (such as [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint)) will tend to warn you if you include redundant parentheses, further evidence that use of extraneous parentheses in `if` statements is considered an anti-pattern by many:

   [image]

   Needless to say, if you need parentheses, then, of course, use them. E.g.:

   ```swift
   if (a && b) || (c && d) { ... }
   ```
3. Regarding the redundant use of parentheses in the Boolean `let` statements, that is more of question of personal taste and you should do whatever makes your code easiest to understand. I am sympathetic to the use of parentheses in that scenario (though I generally would not, personally).
4. As an aside, if you are dealing with ranges of numeric values, you might consider using `Range` or `ClosedRange` type, which has `lowerBound` and `upperBound` properties, e.g.

   ```swift
   let targetRange = 120...180
   let currentHR = 147

   let isInTarget = targetRange.contains(currentHR)
   let isBelowTarget = currentHR < targetRange.lowerBound

   if isInTarget {
       print("You're right on track!")
   } else if isBelowTarget {
       print("You're doing great, but to try to push it a bit!")
   } else {
       print("You're on fire! Slow it down just a bit")
   }
   ```